# Unable to push_back to vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have created an instance of the class however I am unable to push_back the name of the ship to the vector.

> ```
> if (rows->_rows.size() != rows->rows_Size) 
> {
>   rows->_rows.push_back (ship->name); }
> ```

I get the following errors.

Error   1   error C2664: 'void std::vector<_Ty>::push_back(Berths &&)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'Berths &&'

6   IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=Berths, _Alloc=std::allocator]" matches the argument list
argument types are: (std::string)
object type is: std::vector>

The code for the class I am trying to add the data to is:

> ```
> #pragma once
>
> class Berths; 
>
> #include "Berths.h"
> #include "Ship.h"
> #include <iostream>
> #include <vector>
>
> class Rows { public:  Rows(void);     ~Rows(void);
>
> std::vector<Berths> _rows;    int rows_Size;
>
> bool dock(Ship ship);
>
> bool undock(Ship ship);
>
> };
> ```

```
Rows::Rows(void)
{
    rows_Size = 10;
}
```

Any ideas as to what is causing this?

Thanks

Comment: `rows->_rows.size` should be `rows->_rows.size()`. You forgot to actually call the function.

Comment: Oh wow, it's been a long day >.< I can still left with this
Error 1 error C2664: 'void std::vector<_Ty>::push_back(Berths &&)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'Berths &&'

Comment: Well, that's kind of obvious, isn't it? You have a vector of X, and you are trying to push Y into it, Y being different from, and apparently not convertible to, X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.size()` is a member function of a vector. Hence you should use `rows->_rows.size()` instead. It's a common mistake we all make.